# how to specify to only apply jquery effect parameters based on div?

Tags: jquery, html, effects

Ok here is what I am trying to do.

I have a few effects I want to apply to several different div containers. Lets say I have a slide effect and a fadeTo effect. Rather then specifying what the div class/id is in the JS code, I would prefer to just be able to apply the effect by just giving the div a custom tag or an additional id/class. I always want to specify the parameters of the effect on the actual div.

For instance.

```
<div id="cssDesign SlideEffect" [Speed, Duration parameters somewhere]></div>
```

or

```
<div Customtag="SlideEffect" id="cssDesign" [Speed, Duration parameters somewhere]></div>
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your pages conforming to the XHTML standard, you can use some existing but not used attribute, such as `rel` to store the data. It's not semantically correct but hey, it validates.

```
<div rel="slide,500"></div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('div[rel^=slide]').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('rel').split(',');
    var speed = data[1];
});
```

And so on. Instead of `rel`, you can also use `id` if you don't need it for anything else (in most cases, you can substitute the use of `id` with `class`).

Comment: Learn to love the `rel` tag. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid XHTML, but you can always add non-standard attributes to html tags.

```
<div id="cssDesign" SlideEffect="Speed,Duration"></div>
```

Then you can write your selectors based on the attribute.

```
$("div[SlideEffect]").mouseover(function() {
    var speed = parseInt($(this).attr("SlideEffect").split(',')[0]);
    var duration = parseInt($(this).attr("SlideEffect").split(',')[1]);
});
```

(Read more about attribute selectors [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).)

Comment: If you use this approach (which I like), I suggest using a `data-` prefix on your custom attributes. That makes it future compatible with HTML5 http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: That makes sense for declaring the parameters, thanks!
Here is my code:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});

So instead of declaring to apply a slide effect to the div class, how would declare to use the effect within the div?

Comment: It's no different, only instead of using `$(this).attr("SlideEffect")` you would use `$("#slideleft").attr("SlideEffect")`. In my code I created a mouseover event, but that was just for completeness.

Comment: @Michael: That's a good suggestion, and one I should follow more myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using custom tags or attributes is generally not recomended (the HTML document will not pass the validation, that could affect indexing by search engines). In similar situation i used one of the proper html tags, like class or id and place parsable info there:

```
<div id="mydiv_slide_500">...</div>
```

Then you have to extract the attribute value, and parse it with split('_'). It is a more complicated than using custom tags, but you get the valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my complete JS n00bish here..

I can't figure out how to plug that in here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slidemarginleft button').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
```